# Caching npm version on TravisCI

Tags: node.js, npm, travis-ci

I have this travis.yml file:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - '8'
  - '7'
  - '6'
env:
  - CXX=g++-4.8
addons:
  apt:
    sources:
      - ubuntu-toolchain-r-test
    packages:
      - g++-4.8

before_install: 'if [[ `npm -v` != 4* ]]; then npm i -g npm@4; fi'
install:
  - npm install
```

Everytime a new build starts, it begins with NPM version 3, and so in the `before_install` hook, I upgrade the NPM version (4 works better than 5 for me).

Is there is a configuration I can use, which will cache the NPM 4 version, so I don't have to update it every time? I don't really want to cache other dependencies, if I can avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

how about caching the `node_modules` folder?

```
cache:
  directories:
  - node_modules # NPM packages
  - /usr/local/lib/node # cache globals as well
  - /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

Comment: I dont want to cache all deps + npm is globally installed

Comment: @AlexanderMills i've updated the answer, let me know if that's more of what you're looking for

Comment: I think you mean "cache globals" not "Catch globals"